# Bring bottom View to Top View while touchesMoved

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa

I have a grid of views, which are being added as subviews to a main view. When I drag a view which was added prior to the next one, and try to drag it underlays the view rather than overlay that view. How can I fix that content while the view are being dragged on touchesMoved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourView];
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way, You can import

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and each of view set zPosition like this

```
view.layer.zPosition = z;
```

Comment: Not sure what would this zPosition do?

Comment: if view has zPosition=2 will be always top on view which has zPosition =1

Comment: But I still need to get what actually z here is right? How can I obtain that? Thanks.